# Find the largest cardinality

Tags: cardinals

Consider the equivalence relation $E$ defined on the set $A = \{x \in \mathbb N \mid 1 \le x \le 40\}$ by
$xEy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same set of prime factors.

(a) Provide two distinct equivalence classes under $E$ that have the largest cardinality.

You should write down all elements in the equivalence classes in (a)

The answer for (a) are $[2] = \{2, 4, 8, 16, 32\}$ and $[6] = \{6, 12, 18, 24, 36\}$. Can anyone show me how to get this?

Comment: The way you word this question sounds like homework. If that's the case, then what have you tried in order to solve the problem?

Comment: @Chris it's not a homework, it's a test question from uni, and I got it wrong, that's why i ask this question

Answer (score 1):

Prime factorize all the numbers between 1 and 40, group them into their equivalence classes by seeing which ones have the same prime factors, and then see that the two largest have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

The prime numbers in the set $\{1,\ldots,40\}$ are $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37.$

What are the equivalence classes?

First there are those with no prime factors: $\quad 1$

Then there are those whose only prime factor is $2$: $\quad2,4,8,16,32$

Then there are those whose only prime factor is $3$: $\quad 3,9,27$

Then there are those whose only prime factor is $5$: $\quad 5,25$

Then there are those whose only prime factor is $7$: $\quad7$
(Since $7^2$ and higher powers of $7$ are not in the set $\{1,\ldots,40\}$.)

As with $7$, so also with $11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37:$ Each class has only one number.

Then there are those whose prime factors are $2$ and $3:$ $\quad6,12,18,24,36$

Then there are those whose prime factors are $2$ and $5:$ $\quad10,20,40$

Then there are those whose prime factors are $2$ and $7:$ $\quad14,28$

Then $2$ and $11:$ $\quad22$

As with $11$, so also with $13,17,19:$ There is just one number in each class. And with $23$ and higher primes, there are none whose prime factors are just that number and $2$.

Then there are those whose prime factors are $3$ and $7:$ $\quad21$

Then $3$ and $11:$ $\quad33$

Then $3$ and $13:$ $\quad39$

For $3$ and anything else we've gone above $40.$

Then $5$ and $7:$ $\quad35$.

For $5$ and anything else we've gone above $40.$ And similarly for every pair of primes that are at least $5.$

Then $7$ and $11:$ There are none, and  similarly for any pair of primes that are at least $7$.

Now sets of three:

If the prime factors are $2,3,5,$ then we have just one number.

If they're $2,3,7$ then we're above $40.$

All other sets of three primes start beyond $40,$ as do all sets of more than three primes. So now our  list is complete. Which classes have the largest number of members?